# How to hide/show an axes, not axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

There are plenty of questions (and answers) as to how to hide/show axis on matplotlib figures.

How can I hide/show whole axes?

I have a figure containing five axes but I want to be able to hide (then show) one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_visible`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_visible.html) will toggle visibility of the axes.

```
ax.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: I should not work when am I ill. I shall go the corner and wear my dunce hat.